# Longitudinal Data Analysis with Small Sample Size

Tags: panel-data, experiment-design

I am currently in the planning stages of my dissertation. I am looking at collecting longitudinal writing data for L2 English learners at at least four time points over the course of a semester. My sample size could range anywhere from 20 to 40 participants, depending on course enrollment and subject enrollment in the study. In addition to writing data, I would also be collecting age, gender, and native language data from each learner. The writing data would also include location of writing (home or in class) and writing prompt (learners choose between two each time). So, my data would look like this:

Number of Subjects = 20-40

Time Points: >6

Fixed Factors (Learners): 3 (Age, gender, L1 background)

Fixed Factors (task): 2 (location, prompt)

My question is this: Are there any statistical methods I can used to estimate (1) growth trajectory for the learners and (2) learner and task effects on that growth? My first guess was going to be LCM, but I do not think my sample size is going to be large enough.

Comment: Can you explain what is LCM (I suppose it is not least common multiple!)

Comment: I like Judith Singer's pubs on hierarchical growth models. Her papers provide an excellent introduction to the field and her book with Willett is one of the most thorough and in-depth treatments available.  Her paper on hierarchical modeling is titled *Using SAS Proc Mixed to Fit Multilevel Models*, but forget the "SAS" part. It's just a great intro. Her book with Willett is titled *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis*. Other pubs include Gelman and Hill's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. But Singer's work is stronger on exp design, imho. Lot of lit out there